# How to call a function inside a gae db.Model class

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm using appengine 1.8 with python 2.7

I have the following type of object:

```
class Person(db.Model):
  name = db.StringProperty()
  email = db.EmailProperty()
```

and the person's pictures:

```
class Photo(db.Model):
  image = db.BlobProperty()
  type = db.StringProperty()
  caption = db.TextProperty()
  person = db.ReferenceProperty(Person)
```

I would like to have a function inside the Person class that directly accesses a Person's Photos like so:

```
    class Person(db.Model):
     name = db.StringProperty()
     email = db.EmailProperty() 

     @property
     def photos(self):
       photos =  Photo.all().filter("person =", self._key)
```

However this is not working. Should I be using self._key or is there another way to access the Key for the enclosing entity?

Thanks.

Comment: You have to use a @classmethod

Comment: @voscausa nonsense, this has nothing to do with that. Kwame, exactly what do you mean by "not working"? What happens? Show exactly how you're calling this, along with any errors.

Comment: I'm calling it from a django view like so: {{ person.photos }} and I'm getting no results even though there are values. logging.debug(person.photos()) is also not working

Comment: Changing to @classmethod didn't help

Comment: Your photos method isn't returning anything. Is that a copy/paste problem, or your actual code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example:

```
class Photo(db.Model):
    image = db.BlobProperty()
    type = db.StringProperty()
    caption = db.TextProperty()
    person = db.ReferenceProperty(Person)

    @classmethod
    photos_of_person(cls, person_key):

        return cls.all().filter("person =", person_key)

class Person(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()
    email = db.EmailProperty() 

    def person_photos(self):

        return Photo.photos_of_person(self.key())
```

Comment: There is no need for a class method.  photos should read `return self.all().filter("person = ",self.key())`.  Though this returns a query and not photos.

Answer (score 1):

If this is your full code, you don't seem to be actually returning any value in your photos method. Rather than assigning to a local variable called `photos`, you actually need to return that value.

(Please ignore the inaccurate comments requesting you use a classmethod. That is obviously wrong, because you need to access the current key value, so it is an instance method, not a classmethod.)